# Assert struct equality in OCHamcrest

Tags: objective-c, hamcrest

Say I want to assert that two structs are equivalent:

```
// Using CGPoint here for brevity, but my question applies to any struct type
CGPoint a = CGPointMake(1, 2);
CGPoint b = CGPointMake(1, 2);
STAssertEquals(a, b, @"this works");
assertThat(a, equalTo(b));
```

Is there no way to write an assertion using Hamcrest that works like the `STAssertEquals` above? The `assertThat` line fails to compile as the macros expect `id` parameters, which structs are not. I tried variations of the `equalTo` matcher, such as `sameInstance`, but they all seem to require `id` typed parameters. Next, I thought a good workaround would be to assert that an arbitrary expression has a `YES` or `NO` value. Something like this:

```
assertThat(a == b);
```

or this:

```
assertThat(a == b, isTrue());
```

But I don't see anything like this in Hamcrest.

Am I am missing something obvious? Clearly I can accomplish what I want to do by using the SenTest macros such as `STAssertEquals`, but I had expected it to be simple to implement these assertions using Hamcrest, so that all my assertions have a consistent style.

I also know that I can do this by implementing a custom Hamcrest matcher for the particular structs I am comparing. But I was really looking for a simple assertion/matcher that can just compare any C structs for simple bytewise equality.

Perhaps it's simply the case that none of the possibilities I have mentioned are possible out of the box with Hamcrest. If that's true, I'll accept a convincing explanation to this effect as the Answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OCHamcrest is designed to check objects for matches, so `assertThat` takes an argument as the first parameter (and a matcher as the second).

There is limited support for scalars. For example, you can say

```
assertThatInteger(a, equalToInteger(b));
```

A change has been sent to me for an NSValue matcher, but I haven't had time to review it yet. It opens the door to NSPoint, NSSize, etc. But still, scalar support in OCHamcrest is a workaround.

For your own structs, I'd use `STAssertEquals`. The problem is that it's an all-or-nothing equality comparison, which may make your tests brittle. If that happens, it would be nicer to write your own custom matcher that supports per-field matching. (I'll try to make the NSValue matcher something you can subclass.)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I agree that wholesale equality testing of structs with more than a couple of elements can make for brittle tests. It's hard for me to even see much of a use for that.